Is this treehouse platform structurally sound?
We are having a tree house built for our kids and I thought we had picked a skilled person to do the job (they run a treehouse business and have done many) but I am now concerned this isn't going well.
I saw today they used a foam for the posts. I asked and they said it was structural foam used to constructs decks so it is structurally safe. But now, I'm questioning the build so far. I've posted elsewhere and was told that it is all a mess. I did talk to the builder today and told him my concerns and he said that they would still be adding some more support. He mentioned knee bracing and something else but I am not sure what it was. see pics here 

it looks unfinished, you say it's unfinished,  when it's finished it might be good.

You either stop it or you let him finish.

How deep do the posts go, and what are they resting on? The foam may just be to help hold them vertical during construction, rather than being structural. I have a platform for rain water barrels that is built to carry 2,000 lb, and its legs are pressure treated 4x4s that go down to the frost line, with a small amount of concrete at the bottom of the holes mostly because I was feeling paranoid.

There is nothing of concern that I see from the pictures.

The foam is actually a brilliant idea.  Where as concrete will crack, allow water to be trapped next to the wood and promote rot, the foam actually seals the posts.  I believe the builder knows what he is doing.

Assuming he's not done yet with the supports for the joists on the end away from the tree, I don't have any huge concerns either.  Though having half of the main support beams connected to the tree and the other half in the ground wouldn't be the way I would do it for tree movement, depending on your specific scenario, it may all work out fine once he's done.

I don't like the bolted attachment to the tree.

In my experience, building is more than half the fun. Did your kids have any input into the design? If not, don't be surprised if it is hardly used.

I think the bolt to the tree is a good idea. The idea is to allow the tree to grow without moving the board it is attached to.  The tree becomes larger in diameter growing around the bolt rather than pushing a board away from it as the trunk grows.

It looks fine.
The only thing I don't quite understand in this design is why the girders/beams are not supported at the end of the deck away from the tree. If these were on a house, those beams would have to be supported by the compressive strength of the foundation or posts. If you were to stand on the second joist (walking towards the tree), the only thing holding your weight would be the nails between that joist and the beam -- assuming they toe-nailed them together. So I would install a cross-member between those two posts, so that the girders can rest on them, and then add knee braces between that cross-member and the posts. Alternatively, they could have put the posts under those beams (this would transfer the weight of the deck to the posts, not depending on the shear strength of the carriage bolts), and then a knee brace from the posts to the end of the joists.

I was wondering about those beams also.  I thought it might just be the camera angle.  But like you said, they appear to just be hanging in the air, which doesn't make sense.

I agree. The design is mostly sound but it definitely needs cross beams between the two posts and under the long beams.

Right.  Otherwise, those long "beams" do - nothing!
